# What does it mean when ADF says there was an "Error setting value" to "TaskQueueId"?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Getting a strange error from ADF integration runtime (self-hosted):

> Error setting value to 'TaskQueueId' on
> 'Microsoft.DataTransfer.GatewayService.Models.IntegrationRuntime.SelfHostIRProperties'.

There are no results from my googling. I cannot tell where the error originates but it seems like a technical/internal message from the IR software. It may be happening in the on-prem self-hosted IR. This message is not user-friendly and doesn't appear to be something that should be deliberately presented to any end-user. I assumed the Azure developers wanted to see it for themselves... but they don't seem concerned and simply describe it as a transient issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft ADF product group has shared an initial diagnostic from the reported issue...

> It seems to be a transient issue. Identified when there was caught
> OutOfMemory Exception in our web service when internal routing to
> start job, causing job start failure. It could be a system failure but
> incorrectly wrapped as user error

> **We have no record of similar events.**

> We do not have a more detailed description of the issue as it is being identified as a transient issue and is kindly suggested to monitor for some additional days.

... they had also asked to re-install the ADF IR. In theory this could work but it is impossible to say for sure, if there is no understanding of the root cause.